# Android framework is detected in the project

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a new project selecting all defaults for a new project in Android Studio .2.5 it is now giving 
following feedback

```
Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure
```

The Configure is clickable and shows a popup with manifest file. Even after that the project is not creating correctly. Heres a screenshot

[image]

Now getting following errors

```
    10:19:50 PM IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:20:39 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:20:46 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:22:11 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:22:23 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:22:30 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:22:43 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:22:45 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:22:47 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:23:07 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:23:09 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:23:12 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
10:23:13 PM IllegalStateException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (Theme to render layout with)[null]: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/rendering/ManifestInfo.getActivityThemes must not return null
```

Comment: "not creating correctly"... explain the problem, what file/folder/structure error you are facing.

Comment: Its a fresh project creation on windows 7 using Android studio 0.2.5. I am not changing the defaults and project is not getting creating properly with many files missing like their is no build.gradle within module etc, neither the project builds not compiles ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When installing newer versions from SDK Manager I did not select "Android Support Repository". Now after installing it the projects are getting created normally.

Comment: I did not found anywhere in documentation that this component is required for normal project creation. Was banging my head for an hours before founding this post. Thank you.

Comment: glad it helped, for me too it was hit and trial until i stumbled upon this piece of knowledge ...

Comment: i dont think this is the actual solution to this problem.