# 'android studio frameworks detected' when opening some Busy Coder sample files

Tags: android, android-studio, frameworks

When opening some 'Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development' sample files in android studio (1.4, jdk 1.7.0_80) on some platforms I get a message 'android studio frameworks detected' and can't resolve this / get the code to run.

I've tried the following fixes with no luck: [Android framework is detected in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386154/android-framework-is-detected-in-the-project/18394291#18394291), [Frameworks detected in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231460/frameworks-detected-in-android-studio)

I don't have this problem with other projects on these systems (mine or some Busy Coder samples).
Affected systems: AS 1.4 on ubuntu 14.04, ubuntu 15.10, windows 10.
Not affected: AS 1.4 on OS X El Capitan.

Any advice on how I can fix my AS installation to run these projects (in the EmPubLite-AndroidStudio folder)?

Comment: "I get a message 'android studio frameworks detected'" -- I'm not sure that is indicative of a problem. What does "can't... get the code to run" mean?

Comment: When I go through the suggested corrections, at a run box I get a message 'androidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag'.  I just can't run the sample on an emulator or other device

Comment: How did you import the project, specifically?

Comment: Open project ... go to unzipped copy.

Comment: Try New > Import Project instead.

Comment: still getting frameworks detected

Comment: What specific directory are you trying to import? It should be something like `EmPubLite-AndroidStudio/T2-Project/EmPubLite/` (relative to wherever you downloaded this stuff).

Comment: fixed! doh! I was attempting to import / open .../T2-Project.  Sorry for the bother, thanks for the help.  Should I just delete this question or do you want to add an answer and I'll select as solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, unless you created or successfully imported the project previously, always bring a new project into Android Studio using New > Import Project. Use Open only for stuff that you know is set up for Android Studio on your development machine.

Second, make sure that what you are importing is the actual project directory itself. A typical Android Studio project will have a `build.gradle` and a `settings.gradle` in the project root — that is the directory that you want to designate as what you are importing.