# Framework detected in android studio. Can't open project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

After cloning https://github.com/prasang7/Mobile-applications in my system, when I'm opening any of the project among this repo, android studio shows an error. It says "*framework detected in android studio - configure*". Also No directories or files are listed/visible in project structure on left hand side of android studio.

Here's a link to screenshot of android studio: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkgt9otv25vthb1/Screenshot%20from%202016-03-03%2023%3A48%3A08.png?dl=0

I can't find gradle files, as well as res files in android options in project structure.

I've already checked with these solutions, but none of them worked for me:-

[Frameworks detected in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231460/frameworks-detected-in-android-studio)

[Android framework is detected in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386154/android-framework-is-detected-in-the-project)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These project are not build from Android Studio.

So, you need to import them.

In Android Studio

> File > New > Import Project